# When I scroll UIPickerView it bounces back to the first one

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know a lot of questions about UIPickerView here, but I think none of them solve my problem.

When I scroll on UIPickerView down, it immediatly comes back to the first one, so I can never scroll to an element that I want to. And it also can fly to the right/left side when I move my finger that way.

However, the scroll move doesn't work, but I touch on the element I want, it work, but the second time, it scroll back to the first and then go to the one I touched.

I think it's wried and troubles me for few days.

I just drag a UIPickerView to StoryBoard here full code:

```
@implementation AddClassViewController
{
    NSArray *itemArray;
    BOOL firstTimeLoad;
}

@synthesize itemTextField;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    itemArray = @[@"大一上学期", @"大一下学期",@"大二上学期", @"大二下学期",@"大三上学期", @"大三下学期",@"大四上学期", @"大四下学期",@"大五上学期", @"大五下学期"];
    
    firstTimeLoad = YES;
    self.itemPicker.hidden = YES;
    self.toolBarCancelDone.hidden = YES;
    
    //add pickerview
    self.itemPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.itemPicker.delegate = self;
    [self.itemPicker reloadAllComponents];
    [self.itemPicker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    
    self.itemTextField.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark - pickerView
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return itemArray[row];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return itemArray.count;
}

- (IBAction)itemCancel:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.1 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         self.itemPicker.hidden = YES;
                         self.toolBarCancelDone.hidden = YES;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){   }];
}

- (IBAction)itemDone:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    self.itemTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[itemArray objectAtIndex:[self.itemPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.1 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         self.itemPicker.hidden = YES;
                         self.toolBarCancelDone.hidden = YES;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){  }];
}

//UITextFieldDelegate
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.1 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{ 
                         self.itemPicker.hidden = NO;
                         self.toolBarCancelDone.hidden = NO;
                         self.itemTextField.text = @"";
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){   }];
    
    self.itemPicker.hidden = NO;
    self.toolBarCancelDone.hidden = NO;
    self.itemTextField.text = @"";
    
    return NO;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return  YES;
}
- (IBAction)cancelButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (IBAction)fetchClasses:(UIButton *)sender {
    //fetch data and call the callback
}
- (void)requestClassesInfo:(NSURL *)url withCallback:(VerifyClassesBlock)callback{
    //data fetch callback function
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfItem:(NSString *)itemNum{
    //return a term number
}
@end
```

And I think there is nothing more about UIPickerView. Cloud it caused by AutoLayout? Because I didn't set size of it.

---

## UPDATE

add didSelectRow function will solve this problem:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    [self.itemPicker reloadAllComponents];
}
```

thanks Linus G.

Comment: provide the related code :-)

Comment: @thorb65 Hi, I just update the question.

Comment: There should be one more function named `didSelectRow`. Can you show your code in there please?

Comment: @LinusG. OMG, I don't have that function... I just put a toolbar above the UIPickerView and push a Done Button when I finish selection so the function will get the row and give the value back to a textField. But now I can just hit on some index in the UIPickerView to select rather than scroll to select.

Comment: Can you post the full code regarding the `UIPickerView`?

Comment: @LinusG. Hi, I just updated the question, and put all code there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Include the function and see whether that fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the function `didSelectRow` for the picker view to fully work.

Hope that helps :)